# How to find number of tokens in gensim model

Tags: python-3.x, gensim

This is the code for my model using **Gensim.i** run it and it returned a tuple. I wanna know that which one is the number of tokens?

```
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(mylist5,size=100, sg=0, window=5, alpha=0.05, min_count=5, workers=12, iter=20, cbow_mean=1, hs=0, negative=15)

model.train(mylist5, total_examples=len(mylist5), epochs=10)
```

The value that was returned by my model is: I need to know what is this?

```
 (167131589, 208757070)
```

I wanna know what is the number of tokens?

Comment: [This line of code](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/47103081026392eb6f6754c6589df1b78035ba2c/gensim/models/base_any2vec.py#L573) tells you what the tuple is. You likely want `model.vocabulary`, `model.wv.vocab` or something else of the sort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already passed in your `mylist5` corpus` when you instantiated the model,  it will have automatically done all steps to train the model with that data.

(You don't need to, and almost certainly should not, be calling `.train()` again. Typically `.train()` should only be called if you didn't provide any corpus at instnatiation. And in such a case, you'd then call both `.build_vocab()` and `.train()`.)

As noted by other answerers, the numbers reported by `.train()` are two tallies of the total tokens seen by the training process. (Most users won't actually need this info.)

If you want to know the number of **unique tokens** for which the model learned word-vectors, `len(model.wv)` is one way. (Before Gensim 4.0, `len(model.wv.vocab)` would have worked.)

Comment: AttributeError: The vocab attribute was removed from KeyedVector in Gensim 4.0.0.
Use KeyedVector's .key_to_index dict, .index_to_key list, and methods .get_vecattr(key, attr) and .set_vecattr(key, attr, new_val) instead.
See https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4

Comment: Did you follow the link recommended in that error message, to <https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4>? (This is a behavior that's changed in `gensim-.4.0.0`.(I have also updated the answer above to reflect something that will work in Gensim 4.0+.)

Answer (score 1):

[Gensim Code](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/47103081026392eb6f6754c6589df1b78035ba2c/gensim/models/base_any2vec.py#L573)

The Gensim Github Line573 Shows that model.train returns two values trained_word_count, raw_word_count.

"raw_word_count" is the number of words used in training.

"trained_word_count" is number of raw words after ignoring unknown words and trimming the sentence length.